# Julia - Alternate fieldnames for types

Tags: julia

If I have a type called Measurements

```
type Measurements
    x
    y
    z
end
```

where x represents width, y height and z depth

However in some cases, meaning in the case of other types, may not be so clear. Is there a way to make it so that I could call both

```
julia> m = Measurements(10,5,12);

julia> m.x
 10

julia> m.width
 10
```

f.x like so

```
julia> Base.getfield(m::Measurement, width) = m.x
```

which returns the error

```
ERROR: cannot add methods to a builtin function
```

Comment: This facility does not exist in Julia yet. See this issue for a long discussion on this topic. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1974

Comment: How about making `width` a function?

Comment: for this particular case yes, but I have linear programming solution types that have fields that need to be called solution, dual, objective along with w,f,y etc

Comment: I think that it is generally recommended to define the interface to your types through functions/methods and _not_ through direct field access. If you define `solution`, `dual`, etc. as methods, it does not matter what the fields are named.

Comment: Ah I see, do you know if theres some reason behind it (performance, readibility...) or just customary?

Comment: @isebarn Primarily, it's about polymorphism and encapsulation. The way an object behaves (methods) should be separate from how it is implemented (fields). Objects with different fields might behave similarly, and conversely objects with similar fields might behave differently. So in Julia, it is idiomatic to use `width(x)` instead of `x.width`, since the latter is an aspect of the implementation, whereas the former is an aspect of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggest a few ways to get better looking field access, and @DNF's suggestion to use accessor functions (setters/getters) is a good encapsulation pattern. Another option allowed by Julia language is to define:

```
Base.getindex(v::Measurements,s::Symbol) = s==:width ? v.x : s==:height ? v.y : s==:depth ? v.z : throw(BoundsError(s))
```

then,

```
m[:width], m[:height], m[:depth]
```

work. Is this simple enough? In the same way, more aliases can be added. There might be some minor runtime cost involved, so hot loops should use `.` based access.

Comment: It's a little hard to test, but at least in one of my benchmarks, this is ~140,000 times slower than defining `depth(m::Measurement) = m.z`.

Comment: Yes, @DNF's solution is also more idiomatic.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if my benchmark is optimizing away the whole access, and might be misleading. But, nevertheless, I do not see the advantage over defining accessor methods.

Comment: Sure, accessor functions are just as good. In fact, better in some ways. But it's another option syntactically. Wasn't advocating as 'the' solution.

Comment: One more problem with this approach: If the fields have different types, this getindex will not be type-stable, thus probably leading to vastly worse performance.

Comment: @user6847814 true type-stability, but in this case, the fields are typed Any, so it can't get less stable.